# Como verificar se um valor é data

Tags: php

Como posso verificar se um post é do tipo `date`?

Aconteceu uma situação em que tenho um formulário que contém um campo de data:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="date" name="data">
    <input type="submit" name="enviar" value="enviar"/>
</form>
```

Preciso verificar se a o envio do `$_POST['data']` é uma data válida.

Um problema que aconteceu é que o mozilla firefox deixa um campo aberto pro usuário digitar. No google chrome e no edge eu já não tenho esse problema.

Outro problema é se o usuário for no inspecionador de elemento e trocar o input type `date` para `text`. Caso ele envie o formulário com algum valor incorreto (ex. aspa simples, letras) dará erro na hora da consulta.

Minha intenção é validar a data **após ela ser enviada pelo formulário**. Como posso fazer isso?

OBS.: Estou usando o php

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Com essa verificação é possivel:

```
$data = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $_POST['data']);
if($data && $data->format('d/m/Y') === $_POST['data']){
   echo 'é data';
}
```

Comment: Deu certo sua solução!

Answer (score 4):

Pode utilizar a classe `DateTime` para converter o valor em um objeto, formata-lo e por fim converte-lo, a partir dai compare o valor original (`$data`) com o valor do objeto, isso garante que data inválidas ou fora do formatado especificado sejam passadas para frente.

```
//data valida 
//$data = '19/10/2016';

//data invalida
$data = '30/02/2016';
$d = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $data);
if($d && $d->format('d/m/Y') == $data){
    echo 'data valida';
}else{
    echo 'data invalida';
}
```

Comment: Valeu rray, ajudou bastante mano!

Answer (score 4):

Também pode ser feito assim:

```
<?php
//pega a data
$data = "03/04/2012";

//cria um array
$array = explode('/', $data);

//garante que o array possue tres elementos (dia, mes e ano)
if(count($array) == 3){
    $dia = (int)$array[0];
    $mes = (int)$array[1];
    $ano = (int)$array[2];

    //testa se a data é válida
    if(checkdate($mes, $dia, $ano)){
        echo "Data '$data' é válida";
    }else{
        echo "Data '$data' é inválida";
    }
}else{
    echo "Formato da data '$data' inválido";
}
?>
```

Espero que ajude.

Comment: Particularmente gosto também do `checkdate`! +1

Comment: valeu camarada!